# Create session in C# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, session

Create session in C# webservice

I need to create a session to store the Username in webservice.

In this webservice I create the session from value of Username:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Session["Username"] = Username.ToString();
```

In this other webservice I have call the session from value of Username:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

string valueFromSession = Session["Username"].ToString();
```

I have error when I try to recovered the session from value of Username.

```
object reference not set to at instant of object
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: make sure that client cookies are enabled and the first method is actually called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your

```
Username.ToString()
```

I think that was empty, thats why error was popup.

Comment: The username is not empty in first webservice, I have the correct value

Comment: @comex try "as string" in place of ".ToString()" for example Username.ToString(); use Username as string;

Answer (score 0):

Does the client send back the cookies received from the server in each request? If not you need to post the cookies to the request .

Answer (score 0):

check [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] is actually called. you received this error as Session["Username"] does not have any value.

Comment: The username is not empty in first webservice, I have the correct value

Comment: in visual studio add Session["Username"] to quick watch and check Session["Username"] value on each postback. check on which postback, session's value becomes null.